# MDB2 placeholder shorthand with DB->query

Tags: php, sql, pear, mdb2

I just realized that the pear:DB extension is deprecated and I'm working on updating some scripts to MDB2. I'm a little disappointed how cumbersome the placeholder arrangement is. Am I missing something? Is there a shorthand available that is equivalent to the pear:DB construct:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = ? AND column2 = ?", array($column1, $column2);
```

As far as I can tell, achieving the same result (no pun intended) would require several lines and a call to MDB2-prepare(), MDB2->execute() etc....

Is any shorthand construct available for MDB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is none. You have to use `prepare()` + `execute()`.